# How do I start an Activity?

Tags: android, inheritance, android-activity

Suppose that, I have an android app that launches browser with some url supplied when it receives a message containing some prespecified data(some code or something)

For this to work, my class inherits broadcastReceiver class(to receive messages).
Now as soon as it recieves a msg, it needs to launch another activity i.e browser and for this the same class needs to inherit Activity class also. But it is not possible, a class can not inherit 2 other classes.

My problem looks roughly like,

```
import android.content.broadCastReceiver;
import android.app.Activity;

public class sms extends broadCastReceiver{

 onReceive(){

  ....
  ....
  here it needs to launch another activity

  }
}
```

Could anyone suggest how I can implement this...?
I tried creating an instance of Activity subclass inside and invoking startActivity method, but it did not work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The method for starting an activity is `aContext.startActivity(new Intent(aContext, MyNewActivity.class));` Be sure that you place the proper declarations in the manifest though.

[Look here.](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/activities.html)

For clarification, you can start an activity using a context. So just keep a short term reference to one and you should be fine.

EDIT:

You need to have a reference of a usable context to even create an activity. Then you do the following (**using the passed reference!**)

```
Intent i = new Intent(passedContext, MyNewActivity.class);
i.setFlags(Context.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
passedContext.startActivity(i);
```

Comment: Thank uh...!! For the method you suggested, dont i need to inherit Activity class...?

Comment: @Kishan - Nope. You just need access to a context. And to place this flag in the intent: FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK.

Comment: Its saying "aContext can not be resolved". Do i need to import anything? For using this method, dont i need ti inherit Activity class?

Comment: @Kishan - You not actually typing it in as aContext, right? It needs the be a context that you recieved from the OS. You need to passit into waht ever class you are trying to use the context in.

Comment: Is it just Context.startActivity(......) or what you said..? Because, when I used aContext, it saying "aContext can not be resolved". And I dint get how i can use FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK in the intent. Could you please clearly tell me...?

Comment: Now I declared aContext to be Context instance, but now its saying, aContext is not initialized.

Comment: @Kishan - I think you actually need to go back to the documentation and learn how Android works. All of these issues you are having are because you are trying to use the OS in a way it's not designed for. Please take a gander through this site: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals.html

Comment: I am really sorry, you are trying much to make me understand, but its not happening. Now I used your editted code and its saying FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK and passedContext can not be resolved.

Comment: Please do NOT just throw FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK in there.  ONLY use that flag when you actually want that behavior -- when you want the new activity being launched to be separate from your app, not part of your app's current UI flow.

Comment: @hackbod: I used that flag, but its saying,"FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK can not be resolved". In fact its giving the same message for passedContext also. I am new to android and its just confusing me

Answer (score 0):

Here i can launch a new activity using,

```
Intent i = new Intent(Context, MyNewActivity.class);
i.setFlags(Context.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
Context.startActivity(i);
```

here, context was passed to onReceive method of broadCastReceiver as a parameter, i can use that context itself. I can not use getBaseContext method here.